# jQuery overwriting cell value, not filling end column?

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery which works perfectly, except it overwrites the content in the second column, rather than filling the cells in the third column, any suggestions?

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!--#include file="Connections/PSCRM.asp" -->
<%
Dim rs_Search
Dim rs_Search_cmd
Dim rs_Search_numRows

Set rs_Search_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rs_Search_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_PSCRM_STRING
rs_Search_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM DBA.PRODITEM WHERE PRODREF LIKE '84%' AND CREATED >= '2015-11-01'" 
rs_Search_cmd.Prepared = true

Set rs_Search = rs_Search_cmd.Execute
rs_Search_numRows = 0
%>
<%
Dim Repeat1__numRows
Dim Repeat1__index

Repeat1__numRows = -1
Repeat1__index = 0
rs_Search_numRows = rs_Search_numRows + Repeat1__numRows
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<button>Get External Content</button>
<table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <% 
While ((Repeat1__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT rs_Search.EOF)) 
%>
  <tr>
    <td class="pn"><%=(rs_Search.Fields.Item("prodref").Value)%></td>
    <td>Some Other text goes here</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FF0000" class="result">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <% 
  Repeat1__index=Repeat1__index+1
  Repeat1__numRows=Repeat1__numRows-1
  rs_Search.MoveNext()
Wend
%>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( "button" ).click(function() {
    var pn = $(".pn").text();
  $( "td.pn" ).each(function() {
      $(this).next().load("data.asp?prodref="+($(this).text()))
  });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
<%
rs_Search.Close()
Set rs_Search = Nothing
%>
```

Any help would be great. As I said I am happy with my code, I just need it to fill the cells with `class="result"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).next().next().load("data.asp?prodref="+($(this).text()))
```

anyway your solution is bad, because if u have 100 rows it will make 100 requests to server

Comment: Thanks for the response. What would you use to reach the same result?

Comment: i would make ajax call that return array of data for all prodfrefs, and then fill table.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will investigate.